# Ionic list not display nor behaving as buttons

Tags: ionic3

I'm following a tutorial as I learn Ionic which shows an example list of clickable buttons.

While the example video I'm following works, mine does not.

My code and an image of the results are as follows:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <h3 text-center>Select your favorite Quote</h3>

    <ion-list>
        <button ion-item *ngFor='let quoteGroup of quotesCollection'>
            TEST
        </button>
    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

[image]

What should be displaying are the TEST links with the **>** symbol in the far right for each one. And they should respond to clicks. Neither of those are working in my attempt.

Comment: did I solve your question? if yes, please mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the click trigger in your code

```
  <ion-list>
      <button ion-item *ngFor='let quoteGroup of quotesCollection' (click)="itemSelected(quoteGroup )">
        {{ quoteGroup }}
      </button>  
    </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add an onclick event in your button do add (click) ="opendetailsXY()"